# use background image and image on top is not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I tried to create a profile page where the user of my website will have an image as a kind of banner and then it's profile photo.

I have been able to do this:

[image]

when I try to use the `top-margin` on the image, it move the image but also expend the background the image and I do not want this. I am looking to get this :

[image]

I notice that in my code, the image seems being repeated instead of just fit/cropped.

below is the code:

```
class Profiles extends React.Component{

    render(){
        return(
            <div className="profile-container">
                <div className="profile-header" 
                    style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${UserProfile.User1.values.profileHeaderImag})`}}>
                        <img 
                        src={UserProfile.User1.values.profileImg} 
                        alt="profileImg"
                        className="profile-header-image-user"/>                    
                </div>
                <div className="profile-content">
                    <p> more</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }   
}
```

and css

```
.profile-container {
        margin-top: 3rem;
        margin-bottom:5rem;

}

.profile-header {
    width: 70% ;
    height: 5% ;
    max-height: 25rem;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: blue;
    border-radius: 20px;
}


.profile-header-image-user {
    border-radius: 150px;
    width: 130px;
    height: 130px;
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-top: 15%;
}

.profile-content {
    width: 60%;
    background-color: green;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

The goal for me is to be able to display the banner and profile pic as shown in the second picture and keep this render when screen size change.

Any idea I to be able to move the profile pic with impacting the size of the banner one ?

Thanks

Comment: Here's my take: https://jsfiddle.net/L4j3td79/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using absolute positioning:

```
.profile-header { position: relative }
.profile-header > img { top: 200px; left: '200px; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make your parent `position:relative` and a child element (the profile pic) as `position:absolute`. Then you can set `top` `left` `right` or `bottom`. I've used a translate although you could also use `bottom:-50px; box-sizing:border-box` but think transform is a better option here

```css
.banner {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  background: url("https://i.imgur.com/T8YRjiQ.jpeg");
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  margin-bottom: 55px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px #222;
  border: 5px solid silver;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.profile {
  position: absolute;
  height: 156px;
  width: 156px;
  border: 5px solid silver;
  border-radius: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50px;
  transform: translateY(50%);
  box-shadow: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner">

  <img class="profile" src="https://i.imgur.com/LxxvbbL.png" />

</div>
```

Comment: thanks it works just as I was exptected. The only think is that the background imagea do not keep the ratio. the image ratio is modified when you resize the screen. I am ok to keep a proper ration to looks good even if I loose some part of the image like may do a crop. @jbutler483

Comment: If that is the case, you can play around with background-size property but may need to add a no-repeat.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the position of banner as `position:absolute;` then you can set the profile position as `position:relative;` then inside profile you can move the picture by setting different values of top i.e `top:5px` and left i.e `left:20px` others are bottom and right.

Answer (score 0):

Using position attributes.

```
.profile-header {
    position: relative;
    width: 70% ;
    height: 5% ;
    max-height: 25rem;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: blue;
    border-radius: 20px;
}

.profile-header-image-user {
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 150px;
    width: 130px;
    height: 130px;
    left: 5%;
    top: 15%;
}
```

Sorry I did not test, but I think it's a good track.

Comment: thanks it works just as I was exptected. The only think is that the background imagea do not keep the ratio. the image ratio is modified when you resize the screen. I am ok to keep a proper ration to looks good even if I loose some part of the image like may do a crop @escteban